# C# WebApi HttpClient Unauthorized

Tags: httpclient, webclient, unauthorized

I have an issue about **webapi2** and Authorization.
If I call web api with the old .Net 2.0 client (WebClient) there are not problems and the code is here:

```
//old 2.0 client
using (WebClient oldClient = new WebClient())
{
    oldClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    oldClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    oldClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    oldClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";

    JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    javaScriptSerializer.MaxJsonLength = 2147483644;

    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    string objectToSendJson = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(objectToSend);
    byte[] objectToSendByte = encoding.GetBytes(objectToSendJson);
    byte[] serviceOutput = oldClient.UploadData(uri + actionController, "POST", objectToSendByte);

    string jsonStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(serviceOutput);

    toReturn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonStr);
    return toReturn;
}
```

but if I use the new 4.5 HttpClient WebApi return me **Unauthorized**
and the code is here:

```
HttpClientHandler httpWebApiClienthandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials,
};

System.Net.Http.HttpClient newHttpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(httpWebApiClienthandler)

//new 4.5 client
JsonMediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();

if (objectToSend == null)
    throw new Exception("object to send is null");

HttpContent httpContent = new ObjectContent<object>(objectToSend, jsonFormatter);
httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
response = newHttpClient.PostAsync(actionController, httpContent).Result;
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: We speak dutch here but I am always programming in english for easier collaboration with the rest of the computer world.

Comment: Hi roland, excuse me, now all variables are in english :-)

Comment: Hi Roland, i am really grateful for your question, but can you also help me?

Comment: I would be more than glad if I could help you, but I don't know about the differences between those versions of WebApi, sorry. What I would do if I were you is to single-step through your code in debugging mode, pinpoint where the problem happens, and look at the exception message and inner exception. Look also at the various properties of each variable when running, by hovering with the mouse over it.